# How to connect to ibm_db2 database using python package sqlalchemy with the DSN server instead of host/port

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, db2

I want to create sqlalchemy engine with the use of DSN

```
driver='db2+ibm_db'
dsn='BLUDB'
url = f'{driver}://{user}:{password}@{dsn}/{db}'
create_engine(url).connect()
```

Currently my code is with host and port and it is working fine, but we want to update it with dsn

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection

driver='db2+ibm_db'
url = f'{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}'
if params:
    url = f'{url}?{params}'
create_engine(url).connect()
```

While trying to connect it with DSN it is throwing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 599, in connect
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '', conn_options)
SQLCODE=-1336M][CLI Driver] SQL1336N  The remote host "BLUDB" was not found.  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Comment: How did you define the DSN?

Comment: In the ODBC data source we are configuring under the system DSN tab, There we have added name as BLUDB and driver as IBM DB2 ODBC.

Comment: It doesn't look like the [Db2 dialect](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db-sa/) supports what you want to do.

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180001/13155046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer relates to versions: python `ibm_db v3.0.3` , `ibm_db_sa v0.3.6` as at March-2021.

The `db2+ibm_db2` prefix for `create_engine()`  runs `connect` in `ibm_db_dbi.py` which is hardcoded to expect an hostname and a port in addition to the credentials.

You **can** get a DSN connection by using `pyodbc` (as the DBAPI driver) and configure the DSN details externally. The dialect remains `db2`.

If using the `clidriver` then configure the DSN via the XML file `db2dsdriver.cfg`.   If instead you use the Db2 fat client you can use the odbcad32 gui to define DSN, but the tiny footprint `clidriver` which comes by default with `ibm_db` module is non-GUI so configuration is via either XML file or legacy `db2cli.ini`.

The following works for me (using default `clidriver`) to give a DSN connection :

- in the relevant virtual environment: `pip install pyodbc`
- configure my DSN (for bludb) manually in my `db2dsdriver.cfg`
- `db2cli validate`   (to verify the XML syntax in `db2dsdriver.cfg` is correct )
- `db2cli validate -connect -dsn bludb -user XXX -passwd YYYY`
- `db2cli registerdsn -add -alldsn`    (to register with MS ODBC driver manager)
- in the python code use (after quoting) `engine = create_engine('ibm_db_sa+pyodbc://'+uid+':'+pwd+'@bludb')`
- or you can also use (after quoting) `engine = create_engine('db2+pyodbc://'+uid+':'+pwd+'@bludb')`